# Superfish menu - current item highlight

Tags: css, superfish

I am having an issue with my superfish menu. Current item highlight works down to the second level but not in the third level. I am not a CSS expert. What is wrong in my code?

That's the site where the third level does not highlight correctly. All items in the third level are highlighted instead of just the selected one.

http://web182.theta.ibone.ch/vbl/berichte/bildberichte/vereinspreis-2013.html

That's my CSS code for the menu:

```css
.sf-menu {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float:right;
}

.sf-menu li {   
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    background: #a00000;

}

.sf-menu a {
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: block;
}

.sf-menu > li > a:hover,
.sf-menu > li.current > a,
.sf-menu > li.sfHover > a {
    background: #d00000 url(../../images/bg-top-a-active.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -o-border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sf-menu ul {
    padding: 0 20px 5px;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #999;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #999;
    min-width: 140px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
}

.sf-menu ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: none;
    text-align: left;
}

.sf-menu li li a,
.sf-menu li li a:visited {
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    color: dimgray;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.sf-menu li li a:hover,
.sf-menu li li.current a {
    color: #d00000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is the full CSS file: http://web182.theta.ibone.ch/vbl/fileadmin/templates/css/navigation/superfish.css

Comment: What browser and version are you using? Seems fine (apart from the third level overlapping the second) in Chrome 31 **Edit:** Oh I get you now, I misunderstood. Looking into it now.

Comment: Not working for me on Chromium.

Comment: In the meanwhile, can you plz create a fiddle?

Comment: Its because when you have the class `current` on the level 2 `<li>` its passing on to everything under it. If you where to get rid of that class on the level 2 `<li>` you will see only the one that has been selected has the CSS.

Comment: `.sf-menu li li.current a` This line is causing it.

Comment: But without that line there are no more current items highlighted, not on the 2nd level and not on the 3rd...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nVkY9/ Sorry, you have to move your mouse fast as some javascripts are missing...

Comment: I tried assigning a "not_current" class to the other <li> items but it seems it does not override inheritance... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have the correct syntax :

```
.sf-menu > li > a:hover,
.sf-menu > li.current > a,
.sf-menu > li.sfHover > a {
    background: #d00000 url(../../images/bg-top-a-active.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -o-border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And here you forgot the **>**

```
.sf-menu li li a:hover,
.sf-menu li li.current a {
    color: #d00000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So any **a** inside a **li.current** (at any level inside) gets the style.

Correct way

```
.sf-menu li li a:hover,
.sf-menu li li.current > a {
    color: #d00000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```